# HttpClient SendAsync results in error "Too Many Open Files"

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

In my code, when scrolling through a CollectionView (monotouch), I'm getting a lot of "Too many open files" error. The problem with this error is that it's very hard to find the cause of this error.

After spending a lot of time, I finally found the cause, and it's this piece of code:

```
using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage (HttpMethod.Get, uri)){
    var ResponseMessage = await HttpDownloadManager.SendAsync (request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    ResponseMessage.Dispose(); // I just added this to see if it solves the problem
}
```

If I remove this "SendAsync" call, I do not have any errors anymore.
I'm also using a lot another call of HttpClient:

```
byte[] data = await HttpDownloadManager.GetByteArrayAsync (datamodel.uri);
```

This call does not give me any problems.

When I type "lsof" when getting this error, I see a lot of following lines:

```
30u  IPv4 SomeValueHere   0t0  TCP SomeIPHere:51663->SomeURLHere:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Anyone an idea?